# Problem in Bibliography Style (apalike) and table of content COLOR

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, color

I am using Latex for my thesis, and in Bibliography and table of content I have faced number of problems:

1-I am using `natbib` package and `apalike` style. I would like to cite references in following format:

For example:
Text:
In order to identify temporal faults, Feng et al.(2004) used biweight mean, biweight standard deviation, and z-score that was proposed by Lanzante (1996) to climate data analysis. The biweight estimate is a weighted average such that weights are decreased towards to the wings and tails of the distribution (Feng et al., 2004) and z-score indicates by how many biweight standard deviation an observation is below or above the biweight mean (Sprinthall, 2003).

and

References:

```
DIGGLE, P. 1990. Time series: a biostatistical introduction, Oxford University Press.
EISCHEID, J. K., BRUCE BAKER, C., KARL, T. R. & DIAZ, H. F. 1995. The quality control of long-term climatological data using objective data analysis. Journal of Applied Meteorology, 34, 2787-2795.
EISCHEID, J. K., PASTERIS, P. A., DIAZ, H. F., PLANTICO, M. S. & LOTT, N. J. 2000. Creating a serially complete, national daily time series of temperature and precipitation for the western United States. Journal of Applied Meteorology, 39, 1580-1591.
FENG, S., HU, Q. & QIAN, W. 2004. Quality control of daily meteorological data in China, 1951–2000: A new dataset. International Journal of Climatology, 24, 853-870.
```

Plz let me know which style can address my requirement.

2-Moreover, citations in the text are connected by hyper-link to reference list. The problem is that I would not like to use color in thesis and these hyper-links are in blue.
I wanted to inquire how I can change the color to black.

3-I have the same problem with table of contents I mean all the table of content is illustrated by Blue and I should present all the text and numbers in black.
Plz let me know how I can change the color of texts in table of content into black.

```
Tags:
================================table of content

\pagestyle{fancy} % The page style headers have been "empty" all this time, now use the "fancy" headers as defined before to bring them back

\lhead{\emph{Contents}} % Set the left side page header to "Contents"
\tableofcontents % Write out the Table of Contents

==================================references

\label{Bibliography}

\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"

\bibliographystyle{apalike} % Use the "apalike" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography

\bibliography{Bibliography} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick note: by indenting lines of pseudo-code by 4 spaces, you can make them stand out visually from "normal" text. A separate observation: It's a good idea to limit the contents of a question to one request/inquiry at a time. As far as I can tell, the subject of your second and third questions is quite different from that of the first question. You may (i) edit your question to focus it on just the first topic and (ii) separately post a new question that deals with topics 2 and 3. Finally, do first search this site for answers for the latter two topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black}

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage[verbose]{placeins}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}      
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
    \begin{figure}[htbf]
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/studyArea.jpg}
            \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
        \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment (a) the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system (b) the distribution of the nodes in the study site \citep{r33}}
        \label{fig:study area}
    \end{figure}
    \FloatBarrier
    \blindtext
```